# Search the files in a folder - Returns an Error VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, search, find

I've opened a folder with VSCode and when I try to use the "find in folder" search I get an error:

`A system error occurred (spawn UNKNOWN)`

[image]

VSCode Version 1.78.2 (user setup)

Comment: looks like a good candidate for an issue at the VSC repo, or a search in the issues

Comment: You are a number of versions back.  You could try updating to the latest version of Stable or download the Insiders and see if you still have the problem.